# How can I get the same bitrate of input and output file in pydub?

Tags: python, audio, bitrate, pydub

I've use pydub to output a file(chop the file into shorter one), everything is great, but the bitrate has changed from 256k to 124k(why I will get this number instead 128k?). I know that AudioSegment has an argument to set bitrate, but I just want the same bitrate instead manually set every time. Any way to fix this issue?

Comment: @Jiaaro can you help me this question? Thx~

Answer (score 13):

This has mainly to do with ffmpeg/avlib, but you can pass a flag to the [`AudioSegment().export()` method](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown#audiosegmentexport) to specify the bitrate you'd like:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import mediainfo

source_file = "/path/to/sound.mp3"

original_bitrate = mediainfo(source_file)['bit_rate']
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(source_file)

sound.export("/path/to/output.mp3", format="mp3", bitrate=original_bitrate)
```

Comment: I know the api you provide can export the bitrate you want, but I don't know what bitrate I should give if I don't know the input file's bitrate. I only want the bitrate of input and output file be the same, instead of giving a certain value to it.

Comment: @LeoHsieh, the line with "original_bitrate = mediainfo(source_file)['bit_rate']
" will give you the original bitrate, then at the last line, it will apply that original bitrate to your mp3 file.

Answer (score 3):

I was unable to use the example above using the `mediainfo` object. I just found the way to calculate the bitrate for WAV files [here](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/WAV) and used that.

Translating it into python and pydub, and assuming the pydub object is called `wav` you would get that:
`bitrate = str((wav.frame_rate * wav.frame_width * 8 * wav.channels) / 1000)`

Then you could pass it forward into the export function and not set it manually. Hope it helps :)