# How to retrieve mediainfo from raw data in Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, audio, ffmpeg, pydub

I'm uploading an audio file via Flask's `FileField` form and I want to get to its mediainfo. Uploaded audio is available in the form of bytrs.

To obtain a path for `pydub.utils.mediainfo` function, I was trying:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    audiofile = form.file.data.read()
    # type(audiofile) == bytes

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', suffix='.mp3') as tmp:
        tmp.write(audiofile)
        # tmp.name == C:\Users\JUSTME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0wky2_wq.mp3
        print(pydub.utils.mediainfo(tmp.name))
```

But `pydub.utils.mediainfo` returns an empty dict object.
Is it possible to solve the problem?

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747728/how-can-i-get-the-same-bitrate-of-input-and-output-file-in-pydub) quastion.

Comment: Try `from io import BytesIO` then `pydub.utils.mediainfo(BytesIO(audiofile))`

Comment: `audiofile = form.file.data.read()` what field you use to handle file from request. I used your source but change `audiofile = form.file.data.read()` to `audiofile = request.files["audiofile"].read()`. After that, i use api and post a file in field `audiofile`. It work and print result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to read from a file that is also being written to. You can try to use `tempfile.mkstemp` instead:

```py
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    audiofile = form.file.data.read()

    fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.mp3')

    try:
        with os.fdopen(fd, 'wb') as tmp:
            tmp.write(audiofile)

        print(pydub.utils.mediainfo(path))
    finally:
        # Manually clean up the temporary file
        os.remove(path)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works.

Is it worth performing this code in a separate thread to keep app responsive?

Answer (score 0):

In a Flask app, use the python-mediainfo library to retrieve media information from raw data. Parse raw data with BytesIO, then use MediaInfo.parse() to extract details. Handle file uploads or direct data input, facilitating dynamic media analysis in your Flask application.